# Position du verbe dans une interrogation non dépendante

Tags: anglais, ordre-des-mots, questions, comparaison-de-langues

Je n'ai jamais été parfaitement sûr de l'ordre des mots dans certaines constructions particulièrement simples.

En anglais on dirait "Could you tell me where the Empire State Building is?".
Dire "Could you tell me where is the Empire State Building?" sonne faux. D'accord.

Par contre en français "Pourriez-vous me dire où est la Tour Eiffel?" est censée être correcte, même si la phrase contient, au moins d'apparence, deux questions.

Je sais bien que je suis sur le site "french.xyz" mais je vais quand même faire la remarque suivante.
Le comble est qu'en anglais mon oreille ne m'aide plus avec une phrase comme "Do you know where Jack is?". Cette dernière me fait "mal à l'oreille", même si elle est dans le modèle de la première phrase. "Do you know where is Jack?" sonne mieux.

Ce qu'on appelle en anglais "dependent clause" est toujours simple, en français aussi bien qu'en anglais. Quelle est la règle pour les "clauses non dépendantes" (question suivie de question) en français? Le contraste avec l'anglais serait bien utile!

Comment: La question n'est pas très claire, mais sur le fond je pense qu'elle est très pertinente. Par exemple: "Pourriez-vous me dire où est la Tour Eiffel?" sonne bien, mais "Pourriez-vous me dire quelle heure est-il" sonne mal - on préfère "quelle heure il est". Ces deux exemples valent à l'oral et à l'écrit. Je ne sais pas vraiment quoi en penser.

Comment: Les notions de proposition indépendante (*"independent clause" in English*) et de proposition subordonnée (*"dependant" or "subordinate clause" in English*) ne sont pas employées correctement ici. Une  « question suivie de question » est, si je comprends les exemples donnés, une proposition subordonnée, et pas une proposition indépendante. Cette remarque vaut aussi bien pour l'anglais que pour le français. Il semble que la question porte sur le contraire de ce qui est demandé, à savoir non pas sur l'ordre des mots dans la proposition indépendante, mais sur l'ordre des mots dans la subordonnée.

Comment: *Do you know where is Jack?*  doesn't sound good to me at all, just because the rule in English is that the indirect question has the same word order as the positive statement. Why don't you go to [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: The confusion in English might arise partially from whether it is conceivable (in spoken English) for the sentence to be two distinct ones. If someone says "Excuse me. Might you know? Where is Carnegie Hall?", the sequence is either correct or incorrect depending on the punctuation, all but hidden in speech. But of course, this issue doesn't belong here. I'd be happier with a linguistics stackexchange, where no one would frown on language comparisons.

Comment: For your information there's a [linguistics stackexchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) In you question the confusion arises only because **you** are confused on what is called a dependent clause and an independent clause. You can't expect people to understand what you say if you do not use the generally received grammatical terms. "Where is Canergie Hall?" is one single clause containing a direct question (and no hidden meaning). "I want to know where Canergie hall is" is a sentence containing two clauses: a main clause and a dependent clause that expresses an indirect question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La question semble porter sur l'ordre des mots dans les propositions subordonnées interrogatives indirectes.

En français l'ordre des mots des subordonnées interrogatives indirectes varie selon la nature de la question (présence ou non d'un mot interrogatif) ou la nature du sujet du verbe (si c'est un pronom personnel par exemple).<sup>1</sup>

Le fait que la proposition subordonnée interrogative indirecte dépende ou non d'une proposition principale qui est elle aussi une question n'a aucune incidence sur l'ordre des mots de la subordonnée interrogative indirecte.

Ainsi dans les deux phrases suivantes, le cas de la subordonnée doit être étudié exactement de la même façon :

> (1) Pourriez-vous me dire où est la Tour Eiffel ?
> (2) Je ne savais pas où est la Tour Eiffel.

Seule la phrase (1) est une question directe et doit se terminer pas un point d'interrogation.

### Le sujet se place devant le verbe :

1- Dans le cas d'une subordonnée comportant une interrogation totale (subordonnée introduite par *si*) :

> Il m'a demandé si mes enfants ont été reçus au bac.
> Peux-tu me dire s'ils ont eu leur bac ?

2- Quand le sujet de la subordonnée interrogative est un pronom personnel :

> Peux-tu me dire quand tu arriveras ?
> Il veut savoir ce qu'on pense.

### On peut mettre le sujet avant ou après le verbe :

quand la subordonnée indirecte est une interrogation partielle (qui interroge sur une circonstance particulière et nécessite l’utilisation d'un mot interrogatif) et que le sujet n'est pas un pronom personnel.
Les exemples suivants sont tous corrects et il n'y pas de différence notoire dans leur usage :

> Puis-je savoir ce que ton patron t'a dit ?
> Puis-je savoir ce que t'a dit ton patron ?
>
> Je me demande comment Pierre a fait.
> Je me demande comment a fait Pierre.
> <sup>2</sup>

### Attention avec le verbe *être* :

Le mot interrogatif qui introduit la subordonnée est sujet du verbe être. Dans les exemples suivants « issue » et « cet homme » sont attributs.

> Tout le monde se demande quelle sera l'issue des négociations.
> Sais-tu qui est cet homme ?

---

<sup>1. Alors qu'en anglais l'ordre des mots de l'interrogation indirecte dans une subordonnée est toujours celui de la phrase déclarative.</sup>

<sup>2. Par contre si on utilise le pronom personnel sujet, il n'y a qu'une seule possibilité :</sup>

> <sup>Puis-je savoir ce qu'il t'a dit ?
>
> Je me demande comment il a fait.</sup>

Comment: Tout est très clair jusqu'à "Attention...". Pour les points précédents, peut-être que la subtilité existe parce qu'il me semble entendre "Je ne sais pas où il est" beaucoup plus souvent que "Je ne sais pas où est-il". Pourtant selon "On peut..." ci-dessus, la deuxième forme est aussi correcte que la première. Serais-ce le cas qu'une forme est plus verbale et l'autre plus littéraire? (En tout cas, il me semble maintenant comprendre de quoi il s'agit / de quoi s'agit-il. "Il" reste bien un pronom personnel dans ce cas, non?)

Comment: @Calaf « Je ne sais pas où est-il » ne se dit pas, en aucune circonstance. Ce n'est même pas une faute que ferait un français en parlant.  De même "il me semble maintenant comprendre de quoi s'agit-il" ne se dit pas.

Comment: @Calaf J'ai mis le point "Attention" pour attirer l'attention sur le fait que dans ces phrase le sujet est bien avant le verbe et que les noms qui suivent le verbe ne sont pas sujets.

Comment: Que veux-tu dire par verbal ?  Oral ? Relâché ? En tous les cas, comme je le dis dans la réponse, pour ce qui est des cas où la place du sujet est indifférente, il n'y a pas à ma connaissance de différence de style.